# A dynamic input for each record of a table in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic, mvc-editor-templates

I have a property called UserFunctions where I have several functions and must assign a User for each function. I have a EditorTemplate to return a list of users. I have to create a field dynamically for each function registered in the database and each field will use the EditorTemplate to list users. (like the image below). I created a EditorTemplate (UserFunctions.cshtml) strongly typed (model ICollection ) which generates the fields, like the image below, but I do not know what to do so that the values are returned to the Model. I thought of using a hidden multiselect, but is very complicated.

[image]

My class

```
public class FunctionUser //Não mapeado
{
    public int IdFuncao { get; set; } //functin id
    public string Usuario { get; set; } //User
    public string DscFuncao { get; set; } //Function Description
}
```

My Field in the View (property UserFunctions)

```
@Html.EditorFor(i => i.UserFunctions, "UserFunctions")
```

My EditorTemplate -> UserFunctions.cshtml

```
@model ICollection<FunctionUser>
@{
    var modelMetaData = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata;
    var propertyName = modelMetaData.PropertyName;    
}




@foreach (FunctionUser item in this.Model)
{
    var id = "id" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 5);    
    List<SelectListItem> listValues = new List<SelectListItem>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Usuario))
    {
        listValues.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = item.Usuario, Value = item.Usuario });
    }     
    <div id="@id" class="field-middle">
        <h3>@String.Format(ModeloResources.ProductDevelopment, item.DscFuncao) :</h3>
        @Html.DropDownList("", listValues, new { id = "PD" + item.IdFuncao.ToString() })
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $("#@id select")
            .turnAutoComplete("@Url.Action("UsersListJson", "Security")");
    </script> 
}


<select name="@propertyName" multiple="multiple" size=30 style='height: 100%;' >
@foreach (FunctionUser item in this.Model)
{   
<option value="@item.IdFuncao">teste</option>
}
</select>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone answered my question in "pt.stackoverflow.com". The solution was to use the BeginCollectionItem package.

Models:

```
public partial class Modelo
{
    public ICollection<FuncaoUsuario> ProductDevelopment { get; set; }
    //Continua...
}
public class FuncaoUsuario 
{
    public int IdFuncao { get; set; }
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string DscFuncao { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ViewResultBase Editar(int id)
{
    Modelo model = this.Service.GetForEdit(this.IdEmpresa, id);
    return base.SwitchView(model);
}
```

Main View:

```
 @model Modelo

    <div class="box-fields">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
            this.DefaultActionEdit,
            "Modelo",
            new DefaultAjaxOptions()
        ))
        {      
@Html.EditorFor(i => i.ProductDevelopment) //precisa desta propriedade na view principal, pra nao dar o erro mencionado abaixo. E tem que remover o template Collection.cshtml.
            foreach (FuncaoUsuario userFunction in this.Model.ProductDevelopment)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_UsuarioFuncao", userFunction);
            }   

    //Mais coisas....
    }
```

Partial View:

```
@model FuncaoUsuario

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ProductDevelopment")) 
{  

    List<SelectListItem> listValues = new List<SelectListItem>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Model.Usuario))
    {
        listValues.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = this.Model.Usuario, Value = this.Model.Usuario });
    }

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IdFuncao)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Usuario, "Usuario")    
}
```

Following link: 
[Solution using BeginCollectionItem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81266/um-campo-din%C3%A2mico-para-cada-registro-do-banco-de-dados)

Comment: Essential parts included.